# Limit Regex to word boundaries

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have some text

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit."
```

And I have a Regex, that is generated from user input.

```
@".*ip.*"
```

This matches the whole line, as you would expect, so I wrap this expression with word boundaries.

```
@"\b.*ip.*\b"
```

Because the processor is greedy, this still matches the whole text. So, I've tried making the repetition lazy.

```
@"\b.*?ip.*?\b"
```

This is better but matches

1. `Lorem ipsum`
2. `dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing`

how can I extend the orginal `@".*ip.*"` pattern so that it lazily matches whole words and captures?

1. `ipsum`
2. `adipiscing`

---

This [regex tester](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) maybe useful for answering the question

Comment: You can just use capture groups like `\b(.*?ip.*?)\b` and then the "ip" word will be captured in group 1

Comment: @ExplosionPills, that doesn't seem to work when I try it in the linked tester.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use `\w*` instead of `.*?`:

```
@"\w*ip\w*"
```

This will also match `_` and `0-9` as it is included in `\w`. If you want to exclude it, you can use `[a-zA-Z]*` explicitly instead of `\w` there.

Comment: won't this return all the words preceding the word containing "ip"?. I thought he only wanted the single word containing "ip"

Comment: @Guido. He wants only the word without any non-word character containing `ip` in it. I guess.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky. For that it will return `ipsu`. `-` is not a word character, so it would stop there.

Comment: @RohitJain I know that, and just pointing you on issue in solution

Comment: @lazyberezovsky. Yeah, but that doesn't seem to be a problem I think. Let's hear something from OP, what exactly he want.

Comment: @kjetilh. Right. Edited :)

Comment: The question marks are unnecessary, but `\w` might be better as `[a-z]`.  IIRC `\w` matches underscore.

Comment: Oh, and numerics...  `\w` is good for identifiers, not so much for words, and of course, `[a-z]` only works if we ignore case as well.

Answer (score 1):

You were already close to the solution. Just replace the dot (any char) by the non-whitespace escape sequence \S:

```
@"\b\S*?ip\S*?\b"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think some words can contain hyphen, so it's better to use pattern `[\w-]*ip[\w-]*`